# Python while loop index error

Tags: while-loop, python-3.5, index-error

I've made a reverse function, it reverses the sentence, however it generates index error.

what the program does is append the last word from s and puts it into rev[],
it then deletes the word s[-1].

```
s = "This is awesome"

def Reverse1(s):

s = s.split(" ") #reverses the word instead of letters
rev = []                    
while True:
    rev.append (s[-1])
    del s[-1]
    print (rev)
return  
reverse1(s)
```

its returning index error as it tries to continue when s is empty
so I think its the while loop statement.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the while loop, you can use something like this

```
while n in range(len(s)):
```

Comment: Thanks mate much appreciated

Comment: Give me positive rating! i need it to get unblocked, Thanks.